# how to get multiple values in views page in php codenngiter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

cities display in views page like this **chennaihyderabadmumbai**. I need to display **chennai,hyderabad,mumbai**.
Please helpme

**Controller Code:**

```
$data['jobCityName'] =explode(',',$viewData['jobCity']);
foreach($data['jobCityName'] as $cityid) {        
    $data['jobCityNames']=$this->hrm_model->getCitybyId($cityid);
    $data['jobCity'].=$data['jobCityNames']['cityName'];
```

**model code**

```
function getCitybyId($city)
    {
        $this->db->select('cityName');
        $this->db->from('city');
        $this->db->where("city_id", $city);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

Comment: post your view and full controller function please

Comment: if you want to display like chennai,hyderabad,mumbai. So, why you use explode function

Comment: In views page  only write like this <?php echo $jobCity;?>

Comment: @omkara actually cities store in jobs table like (1,2,3) with Ids,so  I get  the cityvalues in array format and using foreach function.based on id get the citynames from city table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Change Your model like this:

```
function getCitybyId($city)
{
    $this->db->select('cityName');
    $this->db->from('city');
    $this->db->where("city_id", $city);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
       return $query->row()->cityName;
    }

}
```

In Controller

```
$data['jobCityName'] = explode(',',$viewData['jobCity']);
foreach($data['jobCityName'] as $cityid) {        
    /*$data['jobCityNames']=$this->hrm_model->getCitybyId($cityid);*/
    $data['jobCity'][] = $this->hrm_model->getCitybyId($cityid);
}
$data['jobCity'] = implode(',',$data['jobCity']);
```

For single city use this :

```
$data['single_city_name'] = $this->hrm_model->getCitybyId($cityid);
```

Pass it to the view :

```
$this->load->view('your_view',$data);
```

Comment: but not display single city.i get for displaying single city error like thisTrying to get property of non-object in model.how to solve

Comment: <?php echo $jobCity; ?> in views page

Comment: what do you mean by not displaying single city

Comment: yes displaying only multiple cities not displaying single city why'

Comment: see my updated answer, model now is returning city name by city id, use it as you want or change it as you want

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show cities like chennai,hyderabad,mumbai try this.

```
<?php echo $jobCity.","; ?>
```

Comment: That would output "chennai,hyderabad,mumbai,"

Answer (score 0):

Put a comma there except the first item:

```
$data['jobCityName'] =explode(',',$viewData['jobCity']);
$isFirst = true;
foreach($data['jobCityName'] as $cityid) {        
    $data['jobCityNames']=$this->hrm_model->getCitybyId($cityid);
    $data['jobCity'].=$data['jobCityNames']['cityName'].($isFirst ? "" : ",");
    $isFirst = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use result_array() function for returing multiple values

```
return $query->result_array();
```